# Hibernate template translation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I am in need of a custom constraint which validates that a value is unique. I have been searching the internet for a long time to find a good example. The one I found is using hibernate template which is not recommended anymore so I was wondering if anyone had the expertise to "translate" this code so that it doesn't use the templates. I have tried to do it myself but I don't understand what the getter and setter are for. Here is the code which I got from [this helpful guide.](http://omgo.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/creating-a-jsr-303-style-unique-value-annotation-and-using-it-in-spring-3-mvc/)

```
package com.omgo.security.domain.validator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class UniqueIDValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Serializable> {

HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

private Class<?> entityClass;
private String uniqueField;

public void initialize(Unique unique) {
    entityClass = unique.entity();
    uniqueField = unique.property();
}

public boolean isValid(Serializable property, ConstraintValidatorContext cvContext) {

    String query = String.format("from %s where %s = ? ", entityClass.getName(), uniqueField);
    List<?> list = hibernateTemplate.find(query, property);

    return list != null && list.size() > 0;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return hibernateTemplate != null ? hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory() : null;
}

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

/D

**Update**
After changing the code I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

So I'm thinking that maybe I haven't injected the SessionFactory properly?

UniqueIdValidator.java:

```
package testapp.mis.validator;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; // Added in update 2


public class UniqueIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Serializable> {

@Autowired(required=true)
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<?> entityClass;
private String uniqueField;

public void initialize(Unique unique) {
    entityClass = unique.entity();
    uniqueField = unique.property();
}

    @Transactional //Added in update 2 and validation works after that
public boolean isValid(Serializable property, ConstraintValidatorContext cvContext) {
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq(uniqueField, property));
    return crit.list().isEmpty();
}
```

**Update 2**
I got it working by adding @Transactional in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That uses plain HQL, you can achieve something simpler by using the Criteria API, something like:

```
public boolean isValid(Serializable property, ConstraintValidatorContext cvContext) {
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq(uniqueField, property));
    return crit.list().isEmpty();
}
```

That should check for uniqueness.

Instead of injecting the hibernate template, just inject the SessionFactory which you also should have configured in your spring context.

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated! I am getting an error when using the changed code. I believe I haven't injected the SessionFactory properly. I have added the new code to my question. Thanks

Comment: I got it working by adding @Transactional. Is that the right thing to do? Thanks again